# How do you snap the camera to view in Ubuntu

Tags: interface, linux

I know in Windows it's <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>. However, in Ubuntu that minimizes the window. Does anybody know how to snap the camera to view in Ubuntu?

Comment: You could just change the controls in the User Preferences.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the menu: View>Align View>Align Active Camera to View...

[image]

**But that is just a temporary remedy that masks the symptoms of a larger problem**: The shortcuts on the operating system take precedence over those of apps, so you have to decide between two options to use blender in the future:

- Configure your OS so that it doesn't use the same shortcuts as blender (usually in Linux I remap all of the shortcuts that use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to use the <kbd>Super/Windows</kbd> key so that the OS doesn't create any conflicts).
- Change the shortcuts on blender in the user preferences. (Just keep in mind that by changing the default to non-standard shortcuts, you might not be able to follow tutorials or other help resources).