# Shortcuts using Ctrl not working in Linux

Tags: shortcut

I'm using blender 2.79 in two different Linux computers (Redhat and Arch, both running Gnome 3), and I'm hitting a super annoying issue.

Whenever I try to use any shortcut with `Ctrl`, it behaves as if I had hit `Ctrl` and `Alt`, instead, and any further key hits behave as if `Alt` was pressed.

For example, if I try to hit `Ctrl+P` for parenting objects, it instead shows an error complaining about proxies (it got `Ctrl+Alt+P`- *Make Proxy*).

After that, if I hit `p`, it opens the *Clear Parent*; if I then hit `space`, it shows the *Orientation* menu, instead of the tool search.  I can't even move the view by dragging with the `MMB` (in the same way I couldn't do it with `Alt+MMB`.

That behavior continues until I hit `Alt`, and the shortcuts start to work again (unless, of course, they have `Ctrl` in them).

I'm new to Blender, so this may be a noob question, but I just can't find any answers to it, and I'm surprise I face it on two different systems.

Comment: Shortcuts in the OS take precedence over those set on blender. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8160/are-there-any-special-considerations-for-using-blender-on-linux/24198#24198 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60961/how-to-use-the-alt-right-click-in-edit-mode-in-linux/60977#60977 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53082/how-do-you-snap-the-camera-to-view-in-ubuntu/53089#53089

Comment: @cegaton, I don't think that is the problem.  Ctrl+P works perfectly fine, for example, in Firefox, where it prints the page.  It does not behave as if Alt was pressed after that.  This seems to be specific to Blender or to the toolkit it uses

Comment: Two updates: first, I found that the issue happens even if I just press Ctrl+Shift (no other actual key).  After that, MMB will not affect the view until I press Alt once

Comment: The second update is more interesting, and may help others with this issue: if you first press Shift, keep it pressed while you press Ctrl, then keep Ctrl pressed while you release Shift, and then press the key for the shortcut (P, for example, for parenting), it works just fine.  It's a lot of trouble for a shortcut, but better than nothing.  Steps: 
Shift /
Shift+Ctrl /
Ctrl /
Ctrl+A

Comment: Note: this does not happen anymore, with 2.80